# RegularExpressionValidator for textbox inside GridView not working

Tags: asp.net, regex, gridview, requiredfieldvalidator

I have GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visible="True">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="id" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="fullName"  />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="situation>">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="dl_situation" runat="server">
   </asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="tbNr" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>  
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data">
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>     
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

It work fine, but when I add RegularrExpressionValidator for textbox with id="tbDate" mygrid does not work
This regular expression must accept datetime in format "dd.MM.yyyy"

```
 <asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visible="True">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="id" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="fullName"  />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="situation>">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="dl_situation" runat="server">
   </asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="tbNr" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>  
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data">
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularCert" runat="server" 
      ControlToValidate="tbDate" ErrorMessage="Incorect Data" 
 ValidationExpression=
"(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-.](0[1-9]|1[012])[-.](19|20)[0-9]{2}" 
      Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
      ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="tbDate">
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>     
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed `ClientIDMode` to `Predictable` for `TextBox`, `RegularExpressionValidator` and `RequiredFieldValidator` and began to work

Answer (score 2):

I think you typed "tbData" instead of "tbDate" in the ControlToValidate property

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularCert" runat="server" 
  ControlToValidate="tbDate" ErrorMessage="Incorect Data"   ValidationExpression= "(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-.](0[1-9]|1[012])[-.](19|20)[0-9]{2}" 
  Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: BTW, in the code you posted the regex validator is not inside the gridview template, is that correct. If its outside the gridview the validator wont be able to see the textbox.

Comment: it is placed inside the grid but I showed when I add the code that is not working

Answer (score 1):

change `ControlToValidate="tbData"` to `ControlToValidate="tbDate"` for `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing the `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ...>` inside the 
`<ItemTemplate>`

`<asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

`</ItemTemplate>`
also you need to indicate some text to display if it fails the regex validation

actually what Hallie said is more than likely the answer ha

Comment: I have already placed it inside <ItemTemplate> and </ItemTemplate>

Comment: I indicated ErrorMessage="Incorect Data"