# Validation in GridView not working for TextBox in EditItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to add a `RegularExpressionValidator` for a textbox in an `EditItemTemplate` in a `GridView` control.

When a user clicks on "update", if the input is wrong, the validator work (error message is visible).  But, in the `OnRowUpdating` method, I have `Page.IsValid==true`.  Why is this happening?

ASPX code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvsaldoPV" runat="server" Visible="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        ShowFooter="True" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="TaskGridView_SortingSaldoPV" OnRowEditing="gv1_RowEditing" 
        OnRowUpdating="gv1_RowUpdating" onRowCancelingEdit="gv1_RowCancelingEdit" DataKeyNames="ID_CASSA">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Saldo" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="SALDO" >
                <EditItemTemplate >
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtsaldo" runat="server" validationgroup="saldo" Text='<%# Bind("SALDO") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtsaldo"
                ErrorMessage="Inserisci valori numerici, usare ',' per i decimali" ValidationExpression="^\d*\,?\d+$" validationgroup="saldo"
                    ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SALDO") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="style11"    />
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowHeader="false" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerstyle1"/>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CC0000" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"/>

    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: may be this link can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003490/regularexpressionvalidator-for-textbox-inside-gridview-not-working

Comment: You really shouldn't *have* to do this, but have you tried calling `Page.Validate();` right before you check the `Page.IsValid` property?

Comment: thank you, using Page.Validate() it works! before your reply I had solved problem adding  validationgroup on <asp:Commandfield> gridview, but in this way rowupdate event not firing when validation goes in error, and this is good for me. Anyway your solution maybe is cleaner.

Comment: @tulkas85 I'll post that as answer if you would like to accept it for future visitors to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling

```
Page.Validate();
```

at the beginning of your `GridView.RowUpdating` event.  This will force a check of all the server-side validators.  I would expect that this had already been called by that point, but it sounds like that's not the case.

If your `GridView` is inside an `UpdatePanel` doing a partial PostBack, or the control that's causing the PostBack to fire is not set to cause validation (it's `.CausesValidation` property is set to false), then I could imagine the `Page.IsValid` property not being properly populated yet.