# Enable RequiredFieldValidation on DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, detailsview, requiredfieldvalidator

From some reason the RequiredFieldValidation doesn't work with asp:DetailsView:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False"
        CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1"
        DefaultMode="Insert" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
        Height="50px" Width="125px" OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEE8F5" Font-Bold="True" />
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" InsertVisible="false" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="First_Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="First_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" InsertVisible="false" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Salary" SortExpression="Salary">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="salaryTB" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Salary") %>' ValidationGroup="DetailsViewValidation"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSalary" runat="server" ControlToValidate="salaryTB"
                        InitialValue="0" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="ss" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="DetailsViewValidation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="JobTitle" InsertVisible="false" HeaderText="JobTitle" SortExpression="JobTitle" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
        </Fields>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

I tried everything I could think of, and, naturally, I searched it online.
When I click on Insert, the value (0) is simply inserted, no questions asked.

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547207/validation-in-gridview-not-working-for-textbox-in-edititemtemplate

Comment: No. It's not. That post is talking about GridView control. Mine is talking about DetailsView.

Comment: All web-databound controls are similar, all the more if you use `TemplateField`s and `EditItemTemplate`s as in a `GridView`. So maybe it has the same issue and you should simply call `Page.Validate();`.

Comment: I tried. 
           protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender,   DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Validate();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }.
It didn't work unfortunately.